P10 LED Display Character Overlaying with DMD library

Hi, I am using p10 Led display and trying to make digital clock. it works fine but after 2 or more weeks later without any switch off there is a overlaying start on characters. why this happening I didnt understand. I am using classical DMD library but result here:

The same number appears very faintly above the number but slightly above and below. I am using ESP32 S3 also powering directly on USB 5V to panel VCC. and my adaptor is 25W for Samsung cellphone adaptor fast charge. even I call clearScreen command in every 30 minute but not works.

dmd.clearScreen( true );   //true is normal (all pixels off), false is
negative (all pixels on)

Why this happening and how to solve? Thanks.

I'd consider using a different library. Looking at the DMD GIT repository, there are unanswered questions that are over a year old. This one sounds similar to yours.

change your code so that the second line is not there ... that will show the extent of the corruption a bit better

please add a link to the display datasheet to your question ... also add the code that you are using

It sounds like a memory buffer gets corrupted resulting unexpected artifacts appearing on the display. As these types of displays are normally completely refreshed each frame, the corrupted memory likely in is the processor.
Consider adding:
   dmd.clearScreen(true);

... in the update loop before completely describing what is to be displayed. This line of code was found on line 84 of this DMD example code on the DMD GITLAB repository.

Added later...
Other possible causes to consider:

Some Arduino boards have linear power regulators which require higher voltages then that required to operate the processor. If you are using such an Arduino, make sure you allow for this unexpected consumption of voltage.
HUB 75 like displays need to be continuously updated and require consistent timing. Even though it may make this project pointless, consider removing any conditionally executed code which may disturb the timing of the HUB 75 like control signals.  Test the resulting code for any unexpected display behavior over similar time and under similar power conditions.
If powering the HUB 75 like display separately, make sure there is a robust common ground wire connecting the Arduino and HUB 75 like display.
Keep all wiring / cables as short as possible. In many examples, the HUB 75 like display cable is less than one foot (~30 cm) long.


Tomorrow i will try but i dont think it will be solution. İ dont think buffer can broken after weeks later. Beacuse unwanted leds are seen very faintly. İf buffer was broken overlaying characters should be bright as normal characters

Consider addressing the comments under your question. Also, consider some power supplies can be complex. A USB C power supply can operate at different voltages and my not reach it's claimed power capacity when used with a device that does not communicate with the power supply. Finally, some power supplies are cheaply made. Consider testing with a different power source.

well I have tested and result is almost same. flicker affect is still there @st2000

Sorry for asking, which test might have you done? 1) Clearing the buffer for every display refresh? 2) Changing the power supply for one with higher amp capacity?

I should add, some Arduinos have linear power regulators which require higher voltages then that required to operate the processor. And, HUB 75 like displays need to be continuously updated and require consistent timing.Perhaps conditionally executed code is causing timing issues. I'll add these points to my answer.
